# How to catch unhandled exceptions in NUnit 3?

Tags: c#, .net, exception, nunit, nunit-3.0

The problem I'm struggling with is that **NUnit VS adapter** in case if a test fails displays the exception message plus its stack trace. However, often `Exception.ToString()` provides more details I'd like to see in the debugger and be logged for easier troubleshooting if CI test run fails. Hence the question.

`AppDomain.UnhandledException()` is not triggered for some reason so I believe I have to implement `ITestListener` interface. I did extensions to NUnit 2.x in the past but unfortunately I can't figure out how to utilize the new interface. Some examples I found on the net say the extension needs to be in a separate assembly which sounds ridiculously over-complicated for my task. So I need a working example, please (NUnit 3.8.1)

Comment: I am also looking for a rather simple solution (`ITestListener` seems to look a bit complicated). As far as I know the test runner is running in a different `AppDomain` and `UnhandledException` event also didn't work for me. The only workaround that I found is to throw exection through some custom function but it requires to amend all the necessary places. However if you are using Selenium you can try `EventFiringWebDriver`. It is working perfectly fine for me regarding internal exceptions thrown by the driver.